# I am making a Carousel and it should show the previous 2 and next 2 cards also in line but it doesnt shows the same

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

This is my Component

```
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";
import React from "react";
import "./Carousel.css";
import image1 from "../../assets/Code_perspective_matte.png";
import image2 from "../../assets/Dashboard_perspective_matte.png";
import image3 from "../../assets/Mobile_app_perspective_matte.png";

const cardData = [
  {
    image: image1,
    title: "Web Design & Development",
    description:
      "A Website is an extension of yourself and we can help you to express it properly. Your website is your number one marketing asset because we live in a digital age.",
  },
  {
    image: image1,
    title: "Web Design & Development",
    description:
      "A Website is an extension of yourself and we can help you to express it properly. Your website is your number one marketing asset because we live in a digital age.",
  },
  {
    image: image1,
    title: "Web Design & Development",
    description:
      "A Website is an extension of yourself and we can help you to express it properly. Your website is your number one marketing asset because we live in a digital age.",
  },
  {
    image: image2,
    title: "Mobile App Development",
    description:
    "We build mobile apps that are reliable, fast and beautifully designed, all at an affordable price.",
  },
  {
    image: image3,
    title: "Web Design & Development",
    description:
      "A Website is an extension of yourself and we can help you to express it properly. Your website is your number one marketing asset because we live in a digital age.",
  },

];
function CarouselComponent() {
  return (
    <div className="card-container">
      <h1>Services we Offer</h1>
      <Carousel showThumbs={true}>
        {cardData.map((card, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="card">
            <div className="card-logo">
              <img src={card.image} alt={`card${index + 1}`} />
            </div>
            <div className="card-title">{card.title}</div>
            <div className="card-description">{card.description}</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CarouselComponent;
```

This is my CSS file for the same

```
div .card-container{
    /* display: flex; */
    /* justify-content: space-around; */
    /* align-items: center; */
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: white;
    /* padding: 10px; */
    width: 100%;
    /* width: 100%; */
    /* border: 2px solid #F76680; */
    

}
.card{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    height: 30vh;
    width: 20%;
    border: 2px solid #F76680;
}
div .card-body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: white;
    /* height: 50vh; */
    /* border: 2px solid #F76680; */
    
}
.card-logo {
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid #F76680;

  }
```

This is how it looks rightnow
[Current View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alvnb.png)
And this is how it should look
[Final View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzpuO.jpg)

I want all my carosuel to be visble like in my final figma design and the active carosuel card to be highlighted and shifted a bit as seen in final design
This is all I want , I am new so need feedback on Code Quality too